# Aerospike scan returns with status "done (abandoned-response-timeout)"

Tags: go, timeout, aerospike

Sometimes less data is returned than is actually available in our aerospike database. When checking the logs, the following entries were noticed:

```
INFO (scan): (scan.c:614) starting basic scan job {id} {namespace:set} priority 2, sample-pct 100
INFO (scan): (scan.c:692) finished basic scan job {id} (-2)
```

If we check the scans via `show scans`, we see the following entry in the table:

```
trid: {id} | job-progress: 49.78 | job-type: basic | status: "done (abandoned-response-timeout)"
```

According to the status we are running into a timeout, which is why not all data is returned. In this case, however, we would rather expect an error message instead of less data being returned.

We are running aerospike version `3.15.1.4` with three aerospike nodes/pods. And we are using the go-client to interact with the Aerospike database.

Is there a way to increase the timeout?

Comment: You should be able to set a socket timeout on the policy from the Go client library, but I am not sure if that super old version always does the right thing when that is set. For example, if setting it to 0 (no timeout), I believe some versions prior to 4.3 may not honor it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Aerospike is now at release 5.6.0.9. Upgrade please, and you will be going through intermediate jump versions to get to the latest, so need to carefully plan it out. Scans have been overhauled. Set-index has been introduced to really speed up scans on sets having a very small number of records in an otherwise very large namespace containing other large set or large number of records.

Comment: Thanks @pgupta. We are planning the update, but as you said, this will take some time. How can we solve this right now, because this is a big issue right now for our system. Can we increase the timeout? Or is there another way?